# Multi tenant httpCookie.domain in web.config

Tags: asp.net, cookies, web-config

In an existing asp.net application the httpcookies.domain configuration is used for setting the cookie domain.

```
<system.web>
   <httpCookies domain="www.domain.com"/>
</system.web>
```

I have to make the application multi tenant. Depending on which tenant is requested in the application, the cookie domain might be different, for instance *domain1.com* or *otherdomain2.com*.

We would like to keep the approach that the domain is set in some central location. I would like to be able to differentiate in runtime which domain should be used for http cookies, and not have a fixed value from the configuration.

See these articles for explanation abou this setting: [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpcookiessection.domain?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_HttpCookiesSection_Domain), [microsoft documentation](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/httpcookie-and-web-config-domain)